# Swift 4.1 ABI forward compatibility: implement function that Apple will implement in the future

Tags: ios, swift

I don't care if I have to recompile my app next year, because Apple changed the Swift language again.

What I do care however, is if an app of mine that is already in the app store, stops working and crashes on app start during load time, because the user updated to the next iOS version. I'm coming from an Objective C background, but I don't understand what is happening in Swift applications on a binary level.

In an app that I am writing, I added a function that allows me to add two `CGPoint` values. It makes some sense to do this, e.g. when you are using [pan gesture recognizers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer/1621207-translation). The code is:

```swift
func +(_ a: CGPoint, _ b: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: a.x+b.x, y: a.y+b.y)
}
```

The question is: if Apple decides in the future that they add a `+` function for `CGPoint` too, does it break my app? (I don't care if I have to remove this function and recompile, I only care if applications that are already deployed suddenly break after an iOS update.)

System: macOS 10.13.6 with Xcode 9.4, Swift 4.1, Deployment target iOS 9.0

Comment: I don't think there's a guarantee for anything that Apple decides to change; I've had plenty of Obj-C functions break as a result of an OS update.

Comment: Well, isn't the Swift runtime library still statically linked? What I'm doing should be no problem then, right?

Comment: Yes mostly static with the exception of extensions I believe. As far as the runtime library is concerned since the Swift language is ever-evolving the correct version is (statically) linked and supplied with your app when compiled; based on that I would say you shouldn't see any issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if Apple decides in the future that they add a + function for CGPoint too, does it break my app?

No. Firstly. the Swift overlays for system frameworks are currently shipped with your app. Evne if/when that changes in the future after ABI stability, existing apps will not be affected unless they are recompiled.

Secondly, overload resolution happens at compile time. I.e. the compiler picks the concrete function to call, and no dynamic linking will change it.

---

Things would be different if you conformed `CGPoint` to an existing protocol such as `BinaryInteger` that included the `+` operator in its requirements because protocol requirements can be dispatched dynamically. (Conforming `CGPoint` to `BinaryInteger` probably doesn't make sense, but bear with me for the sake of argument.)

In that case, a conflicting conformance from Apple added in a future release might cause conflicts.

There's an ongoing discussion on the Swift Forums about how Swift should handle this last issue: [Retroactive Conformances vs. Swift-in-the-OS](https://forums.swift.org/t/retroactive-conformances-vs-swift-in-the-os/14393).